# How can I find all versions of an executable on my system?

Tags: linux, macos, unix

I'm working with Eclipse and Subclipse and am trying to do some more advanced svn actions from the command line.  But it appears that the command line and eclipse are using different svn clients.  How would I go about finding all the installed versions on my machine so I can find the path for the version I need?  I.e. `list svn` which returns all the svn installations on the system.  I'm positive I've seen a linux/unix function that does exactly that, but my google-fu is completely failing to turn up any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find:

> find / -perm +111 -type f -name svn 2> /dev/null

STDERR is piped to /dev/null to suppress "Permission denied" warnings.

If you want to know the version of each:

> find / -perm +111 -type f -name svn -print -exec {} --version -q \; 2> /dev/null

Answer (score 1):

You're confused. Subclipse does not use the system copy of SVN -- it contains its own client (implemented in Java, I believe). There is likely not an equivalent command-line SVN client on your system at all.